# Open http in a popup with indexOf function

Tags: javascript, function, http, indexof

I am learning `indexOf` function in javascript and i just have a question. Does anyone of you know, how i can get `http://www.youtube.com` with `indexOf` and open that in a popup to play the youtube video. Not in an alert popup, but a normal popup with browser. Thanks anyway!

Like little example as this, "MESSAGE" means what a user did type:

```
function onCommentCommand(command) {
if(command.indexOf("MESSAGE") > -1) {

// Code for get urls and open in a popup??
}
  return command;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways (Atleast 2 I can remind now) to open a third party url on your document.

1. Using iframes
2. New window

Either you can use iframe and load the URL in iframe and make your iframe container like a modal window. That's not you want I think.

I think you want to use `window.open` method.

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com';
window.open(url);
```

Read the full documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes, thats a good start. Thank you, but i need to know code also how i can let him open a popup when they recognize youtube url in "MESSAGE".

Comment: Can you give me an example of how does your `Message` look like so that I can accordingly update my answer

Comment: Thats not easy to show, but let's me explain. I have a irc flash client that have config in javascript and there is servercommand that i can get PRIVMSG and PRIVMSG means the text what a user did type on channel. I want to get http://www.youtube.com automatically with indexOf and open that in a popup. Now, i have him so: https://gist.github.com/MaleXachi/5693257

Comment: Okay. Let's not go into details of your message. I am assuming, your message contains some URL which you want to open in new window. So for that you have to extract your URL from your message and use window.open method.

Comment: About your GIST code, the code is actually wrong. You are going to load 'PRIVMSG' in new window which is not a valid URL.

Comment: Yes, i already thought that. He must get autmatically in "PRIVMSG" what a user did type to indexOf. It's not the meaning that there is PRIVMSG, because PRIVMSG is just a command of irc server. like: <User>Hello i am watching this http://www.youtube.com, output: [PRIVMSG]hello i am watching this http://www.youtube.com and thats what i want to get PRIVMSG is just a text of "Hello i am watching this http://www.youtube.com", i will try to continue with this code also.